# Set timeout (setTimeOut) in a created function

Tags: javascript, function, automated-tests, cypress, settimeout

I have a function below and I would like to set a timeout.
If the execution of this function exceeds 2 minutes, timeout and the next test flow follows.

Does anyone know how I add a setTimeOut inside my function?

**Function:**

```
function resWait() {
    cy.req(
      'GET',
      `${url}/transaction/acquirertrxquery?acquirerId=1&dateFrom=${actualDate}%2000:00:00&dateTo=${actualDate}%2023:59:00&externalId=${idExternal}`
    ).then((res) => {
      if (res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.description === 'Confirmed') {
        return
      }
      cy.wait(3000)
      resWait()
    })
  }
```

I tried as follows setting timeout, but without success:

```
function resWait() {
    cy.req(
      'GET',
      `${url}/transaction/acquirertrxquery?acquirerId=1&dateFrom=${actualDate}%2000:00:00&dateTo=${actualDate}%2023:59:00&externalId=${idExternal}`
    ).then((res) => {
      if (res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.description === 'Confirmed') {
        return
      }
      cy.wait(3000)
      resWait()
    })
  }

setTimeout(resWait, 20000);
```

How do I create a promise for my function?
I have an example below, but how do I link it to my function?
And then I call the function or my promise?

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Would you help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can create one promise and inside promise you can try settimeout

Comment: How? Could you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promise like this in your code :

```
function resWait() {
cy.req(
  'GET',
  `${url}/transaction/acquirertrxquery?acquirerId=1&dateFrom=${actualDate}%2000:00:00&dateTo=${actualDate}%2023:59:00&externalId=${idExternal}`
).then((res) => {
  if (res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.description === 'Confirmed') {
    return
  }
  // After 3 sec again call function
  await sleep(3000);
  resWait(); // Call resWait function again
})
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

You can call promise function inside your resWait() and get outside of function, when ajax is successfully, So the promise return two reject for error and resolve for success.

```
function resWait() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     cy.req(
      'GET',
      `${url}/transaction/acquirertrxquery?acquirerId=1&dateFrom=${actualDate}%2000:00:00&dateTo=${actualDate}%2023:59:00&externalId=${idExternal}`
  ).then((res) => {
     if (res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.description === 'Confirmed') {
       resolve('Transaction confirmed.'); 
    } else {
      reject(new Error('Transaction not confirmed.')); 
    }
   }).catch((error) => {
    reject(error); 
  });
 });
}
// get promise return outside of function
resWait()
 .then((message) => {
   console.log(message); 
  
 })
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  
});
```

You can call promise function inside your resWait() and get inside of function.

```
function resWait() {
 var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cy.req(
      'GET',
      `${url}/transaction/acquirertrxquery?acquirerId=1&dateFrom=${actualDate}%2000:00:00&dateTo=${actualDate}%2023:59:00&externalId=${idExternal}`
   ).then((res) => {
     if (res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.description === 'Confirmed') {
       resolve('Transaction confirmed.'); 
     } else {
       reject(new Error('Transaction not confirmed.')); 
     }
   }).catch((error) => {
    reject(error); 
  });
 });

 promise.then((message) => {
   console.log(message); 
   
 })
  .catch((error) => {
  console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Nikita Shrama!! then do I call function resWait or function Sleep in the tests?

Comment: ??? Nkita!? Could you help me? I included your example in question. My doubt is how use a function sleep calling resWait...

Comment: Check my answer. @EFPM_S